# Two adapters for one recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a bit of a dilemma. I'll try to explain it as simply as I can.

My app has a page where I show a feed of posts through a recycler view (represented by the blue rectangles):

[image]

This is simple enough, as I've created a `PostAdapter` class for the recycler view where I handle all the child view logic.

Now I have another requirement where I need a page that shows a post (blue rectangle) at the top of the recycler view, and then the replies to that post below it (represented by the red rectangles):

[image]

Please remember that the blue and red rectangles are simplifications. Each of these views has dozens of child views and hundreds of lines of code of logic each.

I've created another class, `ReplyAdapter`, for the recycler view on this page, which handles all the logic for the replies.

My problem now becomes: how can I also show the post (blue rectangle) at the top of the recycler view?

I know that I can modify `ReplyAdapter` to allow for multiple types ([as explained here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b)), but because these are already two separate classes, each with their own complex logic, that's not really a possibility for me.

So my question is: is there a way to keep the logic of the two adapters separate while still being able to use both under the same recycler view? If so, how? If no, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case is exactly this - data from `PostAdapter` on top, data from `ReplyAdapter` below - then [androidx.recyclerview.widget.ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) may help. As its name implies, it concatenates adapters.

Comment: Looks like this is only available in `recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02`. Are there solutions to my problem outside of `ConcatAdapter`?

Comment: @user4165123 It's easy to write your own `ConcatAdapter`, we used to have something equivalent in our codebase. But why not upgrade recyclerview? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions Every version is stable, alpha just means the API may change. Google ships its own production Android apps using the latest versions.

Comment: Didn't know that. I'll use the alpha version then, thanks!